# USB port making weird sparking sound in UBUNTU budgie

Tags: boot, drivers, usb, ubuntu-budgie

i freshly installed ubuntu budgie on my new laptop, to install the wifi drivers i connected my phone's usb to connect to internet, soon a weird sparking like sound started coming, it was coming from my USB port, in which phone was plugged in, after investigating i found :

1. The sound was coming from all three ports in which i plugged in the USB.
2. There was no such noise from other usb devices like mouse dongle, or pen drive.
3. i used a different cable and different mobile still the problem was there.
4. this problem is in budgie only, in windows there is no such sound,
5. restart did not helped.

thanks for consideration.

Comment: Nothing in Ubuntu or any other software is going to make a USB port emit any kind of noise. This is a hardware problem. Take the device in for repairs.  In the meantime it's probably a bad idea to use any of those ports.

Comment: its possibly not since these noise does not comes when using windows, or elementary OS

Comment: maybe its some problem with drivers or something the port maybe operating at a higher voltage then it should, but its true it only happens on budgie

Comment: Software doesn't cause USB ports to emit noise.  Drivers are software.  This is an obvious hardware problem. Your USB ports should not be making noise no matter what's going on in the "brains" of your computer. It would be wise to get it repaired promptly.  In the meantime stop using it, because it could cause other problems, especially since USB ports provide power delivery to devices (especially phones) and this sounds like a short or some other electric/power delivery issue. Something like that can fry other components

Comment: okay, would ask for service, my laptop is in warranty, thankks